# VB.net SaveFileDialog need to Cancel twice

Tags: vb.net, savefiledialog

I want to change a textlabel when you hit Cancel in the SaveFileDialog. I got everything working only I got one problem, when I hit Cancel the SaveFileDialog will pop up once more and I need to hit Cancel again.

When I add this code I need to press Cancel twice, without this code it's working normaly.

```
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel Then
       Label1.Text = "Not Saved"
    End If
```

My complete code for saving:

```
    Label1.Text = "Saving..."
    TextBox1.Visible = False
    SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:/"
    SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Your Results"
    SaveFileDialog1.FileName = Label2.Text
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = ("text files (*.txt) | *.txt")

    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        w.Write(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString)
    Next
    w.Close()

    Label1.Text = "Saved"
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Label1.Text = "Not Saved"
    End If
```

Comment: Do you have any windows explorer add-ins?  Does this happen in a new project, too?

Comment: No add-ins. This also happen in other projects

Comment: Does this also happen on another computer when you run it?

Comment: Can you create a new, empty project that contains nothing but a `SaveFileDialog`, `Label` and `Button`, with this code in the button's `Click` handler, and verify that the problem exists there? If it does, post the code you used so we can reproduce it.

Comment: @LarsTech yes it does.

Comment: @Ken White, did what you asked. And that is working without problems.

Comment: Then you know the problem is in your code, not the OS itself. We can't help solve problems with code we can't see.

Comment: You are showing `SaveFileDialog1.SaveDialog()` twice.

Comment: If this method is called from a keypress, it can catch the Enter more than once. Try a module level static and count how much times you're actually presenting the dialog and having to click save.

Comment: @LarsTech wow stupid! Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are showing the dialog twice, so try only showing it once:

```
If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Ok Then
  Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
     w.Write(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString)
  Next
  w.Close()
  Label1.Text = "Saved"
Else
  Label1.Text = "Not Saved"
End If
```